# How to check for empty table and terminate stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

If table is not empty then show content of the table and does not execute rest of script.
How to achive this? What is the best methodology? set noexec on, or raiserror? or use Return?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if exists(select top 1 NULL from <your_table_name>)
begin
  --do something if you need

  select col1, col2,... from <your_table_name>
  where <your_condition>

  --do other things if needed
end
else
  return   <-- this will stop right here and return
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what the usage of the stored procedure is in context but `RETURN` is the simplest and most straightforward solution.